# Multiple akka system in a single pc

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-cluster

How can we run multiple akka nodes in a single pc? Currently, I've following in my `application.conf` file. For each system, I added different port numbers, but, I can't start more than one instance. Error says, `Address already in use failed to bind`.

`application.conf` file

```
remotelookup {
  include "common"

  akka {
    remote.server.port = 2500
    cluster.nodename = "n1"
  }
}
```

Update : multiple akka nodes means, I have different different stand alone server application, which will communicate to remote master node using akka.

Comment: If each system system has its own configuration with different settings, then it should work

Comment: Each actor system on the same machine must be configured with a unique port.

Comment: @PatrikNordwall : I configured like that, not working, check my question.

Comment: What version of Akka are you using?

Comment: @cmbaxter : `akka-remote 2.0.2`

Comment: Are you sure you have the config right?  I'm looking at the 2.0 series docs for Akka Remoting and the port config looks to be `akka.remote.netty.port`.  If this property is not set, it will default to `2552` and if both of your servers are doing this then the second one won't start up.  Let me know if this works and I will post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the port definition. It should be like

```
remotelookup {
  include "common"

  akka {
    remote.netty.port = 2500
    cluster.nodename = "n1"
  }
}
```

Other wise, akka will take default port.

Answer (score 12):

The approach we are using is:

Create different settings in your `application.conf` for each of the systems:

```
systemOne {
  akka {
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = ${public-hostname}
        port = 2552
      }
    }
  }
}

systemTwo {
  akka {
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = ${public-hostname}
        port = 2553
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Application.conf` is the default config file, so in your settings module add configs for you systems:

```
object Configs {
  private val root = ConfigFactory.load()
  val one          = root.getConfig("systemOne")
  val two          = root.getConfig("systemTwo")
}
```

and then create systems with this configs:

```
val one = ActorSystem("SystemName", one)
val two = ActorSystem("AnotherSystemName", two)
```

Don't forget that system names must differ

Comment: I couldn't understand your setting, please elaborate more.

Comment: That's all settings necessary for starting new ActorSystem, which version of Akka do u use?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to hardcode the info into your `application.conf`, you can do this:

```
def remoteConfig(hostname: String, port: Int, commonConfig: Config): Config = {
  val configStr = s"""
   |akka.remote.netty.hostname = $hostname
   |akka.remote.netty.port = $port
  """.stripMargin

  ConfigFactory.parseString(configStr).withFallback(commonConfig)
}
```

Then use it like:

```
val appConfig = ConfigFactory.load
val sys1 = ActorSystem("sys1", remoteConfig(args(0), args(1).toInt, appConfig))
val sys2 = ActorSystem("sys2", remoteConfig(args(0), args(2).toInt, appConfig))
```

If you use 0 for the port Akka will assign a random port # to that `ActorSystem`.

Comment: If you do not want to hardcode it in your configuration hardcode it as code?!

Comment: That's just an example.  The values could come from anywhere.  I've made that more explicit.